# How to re: match a pattern more than 1 time?

Tags: python, regex

I have a problem that has probably already been solved ...

However, I have not identified my problem with any of the problems found on the Internet.

It is about a compiler or something like that ... I would like to adapt an invoice (eg `"1 + 1 + 2 * 3"`) to a already written small stack pocket calculator.

Accordingly, the result of the required function should be a list which should look something like this:

```
[("L", 1), ("+", 0), ("L" 1), ("L", 2), ("L", 3), ("*", 0), ("+"
```

My problems start with regular expressions. I would like to search using the following pattern:

```
"(-? \ D +) (+ | * | / | -)"
```

Now I would have to find all occurrences contained in the string.

but with the command:

```
re.match ("(\ -? \ d +) (\ + | \ * | \ / | \ -)", "1 + 1 + 2 * 3")
```

I get only the first occurrence of the pattern.

So to conclude my question it is possible to get the occurring patterns nicely individually in a list (of any length) preferably in number and operator but not necessarily.

Comment: wouldn't that be `re.findall`?

Comment: You can try out and build your pattern on https://regex101.com/. It also has a python code generator.

Comment: well that was a very quick help thak u ... ;)

Comment: for what reason do you put spaces everywhere?

Comment: just happend while posting... and the pattern is origin "(\-?\d+)(\+|\*|\/|\-)"